# How can I call Schedule() on interface that inherits from IJob

Tags: unity, c#, unity-job-system

So I have a voxel terrain engine, and I have an interface that all meshing jobs should inherit from. That looks like this (simplified from the actual):

```
public interface IMesherJob : IJob
{
    VoxelDataVolume<byte> VoxelData { get; set; }

    NativeArray<MeshingVertexData> OutputVertices { get; set; }
    NativeArray<ushort> OutputTriangles { get; set; }
}
```

One example of a meshing job is marching cubes, which looks like this: `public struct MarchingCubesJob : IMesherJob`

So here's my question: If I have a reference to an `IMesherJob`, can I somehow call `Schedule` on it? If I have a reference to `MarchingCubesJob`, I can call `Schedule` on it:

This works:

```
MarchingCubesJob myMeshingJob = GetMeshingJob();
JobHandle handle = myMeshingJob.Schedule(voxelCount, 64)
```

But this does not work:

```
IMesherJob myMeshingJob = GetMeshingJob();
JobHandle handle = myMeshingJob.Schedule(voxelCount, 64);
```

I noticed that `Schedule()` is an extension method for `T where T : struct, IJob` so that might be interfering with it, but it should still work because `IMesherJob` inherits from `IJob`

Comment: When your reference has only an interface as a type, the compiler has no guarantee that it's a struct that's implementing that interface, which would make the type constraint on the Schedule method fail to match. Can you arrange this in your code so that it's inside a generic method where you can constrain the type to also be a struct? If no, it might be possible to get a reference to the extension method using reflection and invoke it that way...

Comment: I have a work-around where I schedule the job inside of `GetMeshingJob`, and return a custom struct `JobHandleWithData<T>`, which has a reference to the job handle from scheduling the job, and the actual job, which is of type `T`. Now `GetMeshingJob` returns a `JobHandleWithData<IMesherJob>`.It works, but I just feel like this is a bit of a hack and was wondering if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: I'd say that's worth documenting as an Answer below that can help future users at the very least, and other folks can share alternatives if they come up with any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work-around, I created a struct `JobHandleWithData<T>`, which has a `JobHandle` field and a `T` field for the data that should be associated with that particular job handle. I schedule the job inside of `GetMeshingJob`, and changed it to return a `JobHandleWithData<IMesherJob>`.